# Разница между @Before и @BeforeClass в JUnit 4?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

Разбираюсь с **JUnit 4**, а в частности с аннотациями `@Before` и `@BeforeClass`. Не могу понять: `@BeforeClass` выполняется перед инстанциированием класса теста, а `@Before` перед каждым тестом.

Но! Насколько я знаю, JUnit создаёт класс теста заново для каждого теста *(поправьте, если ошибаюсь)*. Таким образом и `@Before` и `@BeforeClass` выполняются перед каждым тестом, а тогда в чём разница? Или разница в том, что `@BeforeClass` выполняется **перед** тем, как класс инстанцирован, а `@Before` **уже** тогда, когда класс инстанцирован? Если да, то какое это имеет применение, так как я не могу придумать задач, которые требуется выполнять именно **перед** инстанцированием класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден!

Да, для каждого теста создаётся новый экземпляр тестового класса, а `@BeforeClass` и правда выполняется перед инстанцированием класса *(и поэтому обязан быть статическим)*, но выполняется единожды, а не перед каждым инстанцированием, в отличии от `@Before`, который выполняется перед каждым тестом.